# How are these null values stored in a NOT NULL column?

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g, sap-hana

We are replicating tables from SAP ECC 6.0 on HANA into an Oracle 10g warehouse, using SAP SLT.
Since starting this, we have noticed the `NOT NULL` column definitions from HANA are retained in the Oracle copies of the tables, but HANA stores many values as empty strings. Oracle stores empty (varchar) strings as `NULL`s and somehow this does not conflict with the `NOT NULL` column definition (i.e. we have `NULL` in a column defined as `NOT NULL`).

Querying these tables is producing strange results:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM warehouse.table WHERE col IS NULL;
0
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM warehouse.table WHERE col = '';
0
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM warehouse.table GROUP BY NVL(col,'N');
X 503206
N 2377222
```

So we can tell that there **are** `NULL` values in these columns by using `NVL` or `DECODE` functions, but querying them is returning odd results.

We do get proper results once we alter the column:

```
ALTER TABLE warehouse.table MODIFY (col NULL);
Table altered.
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM warehouse.table WHERE col IS NULL;
390986
```

But of course we can't alter the column back:

```
ALTER TABLE warehouse.table MODIFY (col NOT NULL);
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02296: cannot enable (warehouse.) - null values found
```

I can't tell if this is a problem with Oracle's implementation of empty string storage, or possibly just a quirk of interacting with SAP's SLT replication. It seems Oracle should not allow these rows with `''` or `NULL` values as replication tries to place them there but we have not seen any errors indicating this.

---

Edit to add query requested by hypercube:

```
SELECT LENGTH(col) FROM warehouse.table GROUP BY LENGTH(col);
 2377222
1 503206
```

Comment: Oracle does not store empty strings as NULL.  It stores empty strings as empty strings.  The problem is with whatever the ETL process is that is transferring the data.  It needs to be altered to compensate.

Comment: @MguerraTorres: you are wrong. Oracle **does** convert an empty string `''` to NULL when you store that in a table: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=22f123f135999059e75e28940127f77a and the [quote from the manual](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Nulls.html#GUID-B0BA4751-9D88-426A-84AD-BCDBD5584071) "*Oracle Database currently treats a character value with a length of zero as null*"

Comment: Mguerra is right he said empty strings.If more than one empty space it's treated as a string ,try count with trim function and you'll see the difference.Just create another table with trim function that will convert more than two empty spaces to null and replace null with default value and alter table to not null.  @a_horse_with_no_name You're right too but there is difference with empty strings

Comment: @Sam: the definition of "empty string" is unambiguous: it's a string with the length zero, e.g. `''` is an empty string. But `'  '`  is **not** an "empty string". It's string containing only spaces and which has a length that is greater than zero.

Comment: "Oracle does convert an empty string '' to NULL when you store that in a table" Interesting - so how do you store empty strings in Oracle? NULLs are not values, they are a state indicator. An empty string IS an explicit value, not a state. Why would they do that?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I actually just proved myself wrong there, I was working with Schema Level settings which preserved empty strings.  You are absolutely right.

Comment: @SQLRaptor - there's a lot of history involved in "why." See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203493/why-does-oracle-9i-treat-an-empty-string-as-null for a discussion, there are some good sources there.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Exactly that was my point.

Comment: It might be interesting to show the result of `SELECT LENGTH(col), COUNT(*) FROM warehouse.table  GROUP BY LENGTH(col) ;`

Comment: Thanks @FredShope. Excellent discussion thread.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ I edited results into the question. The length of a null value appears to be null itself. When this column has a value, it's just a single letter, 'X' in this case.

Comment: And what does `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM warehouse.table WHERE col IS NOT NULL;` return?

Comment: OCI can do things like this sometimes: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205351/oracle-database-allows-invalid-time-portion-of-datetime-column-values-under-what/297859#297859) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20004679/oracle-2-hyphens-in-number-column/20011143#20011143) on SO. Dump some questionable values and see if they look like anything sensible.

Answer (score 6):

What you described is not normal.

As already mentioned in comments, in Oracle databases, empty/zero-length strings are treated as `NULL`.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements005.htm#i59110

> Note:
>
> Oracle Database currently treats a character value with a length of
>   zero as null. However, this may not continue to be true in future
>   releases, and Oracle recommends that you do not treat empty strings
>   the same as nulls.

Also, `WHERE col = ''` will never return results, because it is basically `WHERE col = NULL`.

It is fairly simple to reproduce these wrong results by corrupting the data dictionary manually, but I do not know what caused it in your environment just from this information.

```
SQL> create table t1 (c1 varchar2(20) not null disable);

Table created.

SQL> select constraint_name from user_constraints where table_name = 'T1';

CONSTRAINT_NAME
------------------------------
SYS_C005148

SQL> insert into t1(c1) values ('');

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> select count(*) from t1 where c1 is null;

  COUNT(*)
----------
         1
```

So far everything is normal.

The database can skip entire steps while executing a SQL statement based on a constraint. If you have an enabled, validated, `NOT NULL` constraint on `col`, and your predicate is `col is null`, the database knows that column can not contain `NULL`, so it will return 0 rows without actually executing the related steps. If you have an enabled, validated constraint on a column, the `NULL$` column in the `COL$` dictionary table for that column is set to 1. But even with a disabled, non-validated constraint, corrupting `NULL$` is enough for the database to return wrong results.

The proper method for enabling that constraint should be (which obviously fails):

```
SQL> alter table t1 modify constraint SYS_C005148 enable validate;
alter table t1 modify constraint SYS_C005148 enable validate
                                 *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02293: cannot validate (SYS.SYS_C005148) - check constraint violated
```

Now I set `NULL$` manually:

```
SQL> update col$ set null$ = 1 where obj# = (select object_id from user_objects where object_name = 'T1') and name = 'C1';

1 row updated.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.
```

Then run the query again:

```
SQL> select /*+ gather_plan_statistics */ count(*) from t1 where c1 is null;

  COUNT(*)
----------
         0

SQL> select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(null, null, 'allstats last'));

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SQL_ID  fjf8bcs2hhb7b, child number 0
-------------------------------------
select /*+ gather_plan_statistics */ count(*) from t1 where c1 is null

Plan hash value: 4294799605

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation           | Name | Starts | E-Rows | A-Rows |   A-Time   |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT    |      |      1 |        |      1 |00:00:00.01 |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE     |      |      1 |      1 |      1 |00:00:00.01 |
|*  2 |   FILTER            |      |      1 |        |      0 |00:00:00.01 |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL| T1   |      0 |      1 |      0 |00:00:00.01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - filter(NULL IS NOT NULL)

Note
-----
   - dynamic sampling used for this statement
```

Returns 0 rows, the table was not accessed at all (`Starts = 0` on `Operation Id 3`), because of the `FILTER` on `Operation Id 2`: `NULL IS NOT NULL`, which obviously to `FALSE`.

If you use `NVL(col, 'N')` instead of `col`, then the database is not able to use this kind of optimization, will access the table and return the correct result:

```
SQL> select /*+ gather_plan_statistics */ nvl(c1, 'N'), count(*) from t1 group by nvl(c1, 'N');

NVL(C1,'N')            COUNT(*)
-------------------- ----------
N                             1

SQL> select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(null, null, 'allstats last'));

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SQL_ID  0zfyk18knxtfk, child number 0
-------------------------------------
select /*+ gather_plan_statistics */ nvl(c1, 'N'), count(*) from t1 group by nvl(c1, 'N')

Plan hash value: 136660032

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name | Starts | E-Rows | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers |  OMem |  1Mem | Used-Mem |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |      |      1 |        |      1 |00:00:00.01 |       3 |       |       |          |
|   1 |  HASH GROUP BY     |      |      1 |      1 |      1 |00:00:00.01 |       3 |  1156K|  1156K|  323K (0)|
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| T1   |      1 |      1 |      1 |00:00:00.01 |       3 |       |       |          |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Note
-----
   - dynamic sampling used for this statement
```

No `FILTER` this time, and the table was accessed (`Starts 1` on `Operation Id 2 - TABLE ACCESS FULL`).

There was a bug in 10g that caused wrong results with the optimization for `CHECK` constraints with `NULL` on transitive predicates:

**Bug 5462687 - CHECK constraint can cause wrong results (Doc ID 5462687.8)**

This will not help me, because I corrupted the dictionary myself. But if your actual query is more complex than you posted (otherwise do not bother with this), and have transitive predicates, you could try the workaround written in this, and disable this behaviour by setting event 10195

```
$ oerr ora 10195
10195, 00000, "CBO don't use check constraints for transitive predicates"
// *Cause:
// *Action:
```

Example:

```
alter session set event '10195 trace name context level 1';
```

I do not think this caused by how data is stored, rather just something about the constraints.

Comment: Shouldn't the actual statement be `WHERE column IS NULL` or are you just explaining how it is executed in layman's terms? It might help to either add that or elaborate a bit, just to ensure the user doesn't get frustrated when trying to search for NULL values.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at the constraint definition.
It is possible to define constraints that are not validated (existing data isn't checked when the constraint is created) and/or disabled (not enforced by the database when inserting/updating).

These constraints can also be marked as RELY which means the optimizer assumes that they apply. You generally only want this situation on a datawarehouse / reporting environment where you can be sure the data conforms to the constraint any you don't want to incur the overhead of checking it.

It is possible that the load mechanism has been disabling the constraint, loading/appending data, then re-enabling it with the novalidate setting.

Since the optimizer assumes there no NULL values, it may choose a plan that would not find them.

```
create table test_rely
    (id number,
    val varchar2(10)); 
alter table test_rely add constraint test_rely_val_nn check(val is not null) rely disable novalidate;

insert into test_rely values(10,null);

alter table test_rely modify constraint test_rely_val_nn enable novalidate;
```